# Php date format for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime-format

I'm having a date format like this:

```
2010-09-21T00:00:00+03:00
```

how can i convert it to 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format?

I've tried following code but I don't think it's working:

```
$date = new DateTime('2010-09-21T20:00:00+03:00');
$status_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

It prints time like this: 2010-09-21 20:00:00

Comment: I've read the question three times and I can't understand what the problem is. Isn't `2010-09-21 20:00:00` in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format?

Answer (score 1):

It prints exactly want you want ! So what's wrong ?

You can also use Carbon and to like this :

Carbon::parse('2010-09-21T00:00:00+03:00')->toDateTimeString();

#### UPDATE

Be careful, you said you want midnight but you wrote 8pm in your php !

Comment: @fabulouseCo but why it always print 2010-09-21 20:00:00? what's the purpose of +03:00 in it? I'm confused with it, thanks!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that ! It's the timezone correction. If you don't manage timezones in your project, don't use it. Just say : 2010-09-21 20:00:00

Comment: so you mean it's working correct? I'm reading this datetime from file and want to store it in database.

Comment: "Your code is correct, so you need to install a third-party library" xD